# Delete or rename more than one file with a single command in Windows CMD?

Tags: command-line, windows-vista

Is it possible to specify more than one file name or mask for deletion with the DEL command in CMD?

Something like this...

```
del /p *.html & *.json
```

This command works only partially - it finds all files with html suffix and prompts for deletion, it doesn't understand the second part for files with json suffix and returns an error at the end saying that it is not an internal or external command.

And what about the `ren` command?

Is it possible to input something like...

> ren "file 1 & file 2 & file 3" "file a file b file c"

... to sort of tell it to rename file 1, 2 and 3 to file a, b and c respectively?

Or is this simply not possible without either redesigning the CMD or using batch processing or scripting?

Is there no utilization for the and character (&) in CMD?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to specify more than one file name or mask for deletion with the DEL command in CMD?

Yes, just list them:

```
del /p *.html *.json
```

The `&` operator allows you to specify multiple *commands* on the same line, so when you run `del /p *.html & *.json`, you are telling it to delete all html files, and then to *execute* all json files which of course won't work since you cannot use wildcards in command names.

> And what about the ren command?

No, the `ren` command is more restrictive. It *could* be extended to accept arguments in pairs, but it does not. You can use the `&` operator here (if you *must*), but you must re-specify the `ren` command (though it is much clearer to do them on separate lines):

```
ren "file 1" a & ren "file 2" b & ren "file 3" c
```